# Automate Form login in website using Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'm automating form login in a certain site using the WebBrowser control. Having the client id of the textbox, password and button login, I'm able to do it.

The question is, can I still do it without identifying the id of the button and simulate a click?

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as C#.NET, unlike VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you could do this without being able to identify the controls somehow. You would need the ids, or you would need to be told exactly where in the DOM they were located by some other means.

Comment: @Slaks: right, in general. What if `type="password"` isn't used? What if there's a lot of `<input type="hidden"/>` between the password and username boxes?

Comment: What? Show me _one_ login form, anywhere, without an `<input type="password">`.  You can ignore hidden inputs.

Comment: @SLaks: there also may be more than one "password" box. What about for answers to secret questions? What if they have the "Change Password" on the same form, with two "password" boxes, both display:none?

Comment: john saunders right. actually, what im after is automating it without defining the login button id. username and password field is alright to define

Answer (score 4):

Yes; you can call the `submit` method of the `form` object.

For example:

```
browser.Document.Forms[0].Invokemember("submit");
```

To set the name and password, loop through

```
browser.Document.Forms[0].GetElementsByTagName("input")
```

Tpassword will have the `type` attribute equal to `password`, and the username will probably be just before the password.

Comment: @S.Laks: he also needs to fill in username and password.

Comment: he kind of did: "With the client id of the textbox, password and button login, i was able to do it." I can't think why else he'd have asked about those controls.

Comment: With no helper functions, this is the way to do it. If you find yourself littering your code with a lot of `browser.document...` methods you may find it easier to try to write a simple selector engine like jQuery Sizzle uses to make the process easier. That's what I did a few years back.